# Selenium with Windows Release Mangement

Tags: windows, selenium, batch-file, ms-release-management

In Microsoft Release Management 2013, in the Powershell Executor step we have configured a step to trigger a Windows batch file. This batch file will be executed on a different server, which also happens be our App Server. As an experiment, we have a simple test case to open IE, access the Google homepage URL and close the browser, a screenshot will also be captured. When we run the job from RM, the Selenium logs say that the browser is launched and the test was successful. But when we check the screenshot it is just a black screen. All this runs as the Windows service account user which is the same user that is running RM. This user has no log on privilege.

If I log into the App server with my own ID and execute the batch file manually, the screen shot is captured correctly.
I have read several online posts regarding the black screen. People have said that the screenshot is black because the screen is locked. Does this mean the RM Powershell executor step must be executed with some other credentials instead of service account? If yes, how do we do this? In some suggestions it was mentioned to install VNC. Is that relevant in this situation?

I'm fairly new to Windows. I've mostly been working in Linux systems and I've been requested to debug this issue here. Any pointers/guidance will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We  finally got this to work.

We were invoking the testNG selenium tests within a batch script. This script was specified in RM within the Powershell Executor task. The main point to note is that, in the Powershell executor task, we must first have a cd (change directory) command to change into the directory where the Selenium scripts are. Then specify the complete path to the batch script to be executed in the same Powershell executor task. This cd command is very important. Without this, the batch script would be executed but the selenium step within that wouldn't work. You would just get a vague "configuration errors:1" in the final output.

We took care of website authentication using AutoIT for IE browser.

Answer (score 0):

The deployment agent does not run as an interactive service. You're going to have a lot of trouble getting it to directly invoke Selenium tests. I wrote a [blog post](http://incyclesoftware.com/2014/02/executing-selenium-ui-tests-release-management/) a few years ago showing how I accomplished it. Basically, you use Selenium hub to execute the tests interactively from agent machines.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me with this!
I was able to figure out the solution which happened to be a simple case of not adding a "cd" command in the RM Powershell executor step. I've posted my answer here.